# Find the two square roots of $i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I have this question I am stumped upon for my Test-Review:

Write $i$ as a complex number in polar form. Use the result and DeMoivre's Theorem to find the square roots of $i$.

I got the first question:

$i = a + bi$

$0 + 1i$

$z = \sqrt{0 ^ 2 + 1 ^ 2}$

$z = 1$

$\Theta = \tan^-1(y/x)$

$\Theta = \tan^-1(0/1)$

$\Theta = 90^\circ$

Therefore... answer is $1 \cdot cis(90)$... Ok I got that but the Demoivre theorem and the sqrt I couldn't understand... This is the answer.. from anwser key:

a) $cis(90^\circ)$

b) $cis(45 ^\circ) , circ(225 ^\circ)$

### I'm following

My teacher follows same way as this: http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/polar-form-of-a-complex-number.html

### Formulas Available

[image]

Comment: The arctangent of $0$ is $0^\circ$.  You should have $\arctan(1/0)$ at which point you realize you can't divide by zero and something's wrong.  Then we tell you about $\operatorname{atan2}$.  So you got the right answer, but that part of your work is wrong.

Comment: So my Anwser key is wrong? @Bye_World ?? It says the anwser for number one is $cis(90 ^\circ)$  your saying its... $cis(0 ^\circ)$

Comment: No.  Read the last sentence of my comment.

Comment: Ok But @Bye_World ???????? Can you do the whole question.. I dont understand where i am wrong? My head is about to blow up to pieces.. i have been doing this for like 4 hours now!

Comment: Do you know [de Moivre's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers)?  What did you get when you tried using it?

Comment: Before we go there @Bye_World how is my orignal statement wrong? i said $tan ^-1(y/x)$ then.. $tan ^-1(0/1)$ ... which is 0.. So im wrong Accordint to the anwser key. How do i fix that?

Comment: $y=1$ and $x=0$.  So you "should" have $\arctan(1/0)$ not $\arctan(0/1)$.  Except that that's pretty hard to evaluate since dividing by zero is not defined.

Comment: Yes your right... @Bye_World But that gets you to the **infamous divided by 0 error**..  Even if i do $arctan(1/0)$ in my calculator.. i will get MA Error...

Comment: That's when you learn that $\arctan$ only works if your angle is in $(-90^\circ, 90^\circ)$.  A better function is [atan2(y,x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) which works for any angle.  You could also just graph it and see that it's $90^\circ$ in this case though.

Comment: @Bye_World What in the World  is atan2? We never learned about that...??? So we probably shouldnt use that.. This is a 10th grdae precalculus class.. so im preety sure we are not suppose to use complicated stuff we didnt learn. And we certaintly didnt learn about atan2

Comment: Then just graph it and look at the angle.

Comment: Ok man.... @Bye_World . We are not suppose to graph at all on the test either... Ima post an image of the Formula We are suppose to use.. One second

Comment: See my answer, I only used really elementary facts.

Comment: @Bye_World I posted the new Formulas we are suppose to use..

Comment: If you can't use $\operatorname{atan2}$ and you can't graph then I guess you're just supposed to know that $i$ is at a $90^\circ$ angle from the positive $x$-axis.

Comment: @Bye_World OK Then.. Now if we are suppose to know $i = 90 ^\circ$ then what about the next question about Square Rooting stuff btw.. $i = cis(90 ^\circ)$

Comment: Guess this question goes to my teacher again @Bye_World ......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I have tried to do my best earlier... but go through this step by step.

$z_1 = a + i\,b\\ 
z_2 = x + i\,y \\
z_1z_2 = (a + i\,b)(x + i\,y) = (ax + i\,bx + i\,ay + i^2\,by)$

$i^2 = -1$, and you can combine the $i$ terms.

$z_1z_2 = (ax - by)  + i\,(ay + bx)$

Okay, if you are already lost re-read this.

If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are in polar...

$z_1 = \rho_1 (\cos \theta + i \sin\theta)\\ 
z_2 = \rho_2 (\cos \phi + i \sin\phi)\\ 
z_1z_2 =\rho_1\rho_2 (\cos\theta\cos\phi - \sin\theta \sin\phi + i(\sin\theta \cos \phi + \cos \theta \sin \phi)$

This is the same multiplication that we did in rectangular coordinates.
But notice how this ties out to the angle addition formulas for $\cos$ and $\sin$

$z_1z_2 =\rho_1\rho_2 (\cos(\theta+\phi) + i\sin(\theta+\phi))$

When we multiply complex numbers we add the angles!  This is particularly noticeable in polar form, but it is just as true in Cartesian form.

$z^2 = z\cdot z =$$ \rho (\cos \theta + i \sin\theta)\rho (\cos \theta + i \sin\theta)\\
\rho^2 (\cos 2\theta + i \sin2\theta)\\$

De Moivre's theorem:

$z^n = \rho^n (\cos n\theta + i \sin n\theta)$

and it works just as well when $n$ is a fraction as it does when $n$ is a whole number.

$\sqrt z = z^{1/2}$

$\sqrt z = \pm \rho^{1/2} (\cos \frac{\theta}{2} + i \sin \frac{\theta}2)$

Everything up to this point is actually on your cheat-sheet in condensed from.  But rather than just memorizing formula, try to understand what is actually going on, and where those formula are coming from.

And to the problem at hand:

$z = 0 + i\\
z = (\cos 90 + i \sin 90)\\
z^{1/2} = \pm (\cos 45 + i \sin 45)\\
z^{1/2} =  (\cos 45 + i \sin 45), (\cos 225 + i \sin 225)$

Advanced stuff:  This is not something you are expected to know in precaluculs, but if you ask the question on this board people may assume you know this.

Complex numbers in polar form can be translated into exponential form as follows:

$z = \rho e^{i\theta}\\
z^n = \rho^n e^{i\theta n}\\
z^{1/n} = \rho^\frac1n e^{\frac{i\theta}{n}}\\
$

Comment: Your work always Confuses me man.. 99.99% of the time since im stupid

Comment: Telling yourself (and us) that you are stupid, will only put yourself in the wrong frame of mind for learning.  All of us were ignorant of this stuff when we entered high-school, and most of us struggled with math at some point along the way.  Math is hard -- for everybody at some level.  https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2016/02/03/how-to-edit-your-math-pessimism/

Comment: everything (with the exception of the last bit) is identical to what is on your attached photo.

Comment: Ok Thankyou @Doug M . Ima just ask my teacher how to do it, and ill understand then. Again im very thankfull for your time!

Answer (score 3):

**Solution $1$**

Let $z=x+iy\in \Bbb C$ such that $z^2=i$.  then $z^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi=i$. It follows that

$$
x^2=y^2\iff x=\pm y\\
2xyi=i \iff x=\frac 1 {2y}
$$

Then, $x=\pm\frac 1 {2x}$, we get that $x=\pm\sqrt2/2$ , so we get $z_1=\sqrt 2/2+\sqrt 2 /2i$, $z_2=-z_1$.

---

Having the $x,y$ coordinates, you can put these numbers in polar form if you please.

---

**Solution $2$**

Let $z=r \operatorname{cis}(\theta)$. We want $z^2=i$, but $z^2=r^2 \operatorname{cis}(2\theta)$.

Now, $|i|=1$, $|z^2|=r^2$ and as we want $z^2=i$, we need $r^2=1$, i.e $r=1$.

Comparing angles now, we need $2\theta=90^\circ+360^\circ k$, that is, $\theta=45^\circ+180^\circ k$ or $\theta_1=45^\circ,\theta_2=225^\circ$ (note that if you add more $180^\circ$s, we get back $45,225,45,\cdots$.

So the **two** square roots of $i$ are $z_1=1\cdot \operatorname{cis}(45^\circ)$ and $z_2= 1\cdot \operatorname{cis}(225^\circ)$.

---

I suggest you stop looking at your formulas and start thinking about the problem without them, as shown here, they're not needed, the only fact you 'needed to know' was that $i$'s angle is $90^\circ$.

Comment: Dude looking at your math confuses me.... Can you take a look at the image, where it shows the formulas we are suppose to use for my test review?

Comment: @Dsafds Done...

Comment: YoTengo, thanks a lot for your time sir, but one thing... Since im stupid, can you go one at a time? Like Do:

Writing $i$ as a complex number in polar form:

$blahblahblah$

Finding the two squareroot of $i$:


$blahblahblah$


I would love it if you can put it in that format . I honestly dont know where you convert i as complex number to polar form..

Comment: @Dsafds I never really did, I just said that the modulus of $i$, i.e $|i|$ is $1$, and its argument (angle) is $90^\circ$ (with this you can however write it in polar form: $i=|i|\cdot \operatorname{cis}(90^\circ )$). As said in another answer, saying you're stupid serves no good.

Comment: Finished with test today :) .  This question is now easy.. Ima anwser it.

Answer (score 1):

You have $i = e^{i\pi/2}$ so this has two square roots, $e^{i\pi/4}$ and $-e^{i\pi/4} = e^{5i\pi/4}.$

Comment: We didnt learn about that... Im not going that complicated -.-

Comment: You're missing some $i$'s.

Comment: Aye Aye, Captain Bye_World.

Comment: Nothing complicated @dsafds.  Invoke the Euler Theorem $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i\sin(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, let $z=x+iy$ where $x$ and $y$ are real-valued numbers.  We can express $z$ in [Polar Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Complex_numbers) as $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\arctan(x,y)}$ where the [Arctangent Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) $\arctan(x,y)$ is given by

$$
\arctan(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\arctan(y/x)&,x>0\\\\
\pi+\arctan(y/x)&,x<0,y>0\\\\
-\pi+\arctan(y/x)&,x<0,y<0\\\\
\pi/2&,x=0,y>0\\\\
-\pi/2&,x=0,y<0
\end{cases}$$

Then, the square root of $z$, $z^{1/2}$ is one of the two values

$$z^{1/2}=\pm (x^2+y^2)^{1/4}e^{i\arctan(x,y)/2} \tag 1$$

We can convert $z^{1/2}$ back to rectangular coordinates using [Euler's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Applications_in_complex_number_theory) on $(1)$.  Proceeding accordingly gives

$$\begin{align}
z^{1/2}&=\pm (x^2+y^2)^{1/4}\left(\cos\left(\frac12 \arctan(x,y)\right)+i\sin\left(\frac12\arctan(x,y)\right)\right)\\\\
&=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}{2}}\pm i\,\text{sgn}(y)\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{2}}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

where in arriving at $(2)$ we used the [Half-Angle Formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) for the sine and cosine funcitons.

Applying $(2)$ to the case for which $x=0$ and $y=1$, we find that

$$\sqrt{i}=\pm\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If the answer is not useful, I am happy to delete.  Please advise.  -Mark